# Vue js использовать компоненты в цикле

Tags: vue.js

пробую создать компонент

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>vue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px" id="app">
    <child message="hello!"></child>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>

      <tbody>
        <user :users="users"></user>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript">
  Vue.component('user', {
    // declare the props
    props: ['users'],
    // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
    // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
    template: `        
        <tr v-for="user in users">
          <td @click="selectResponder(user)"> {{user.name}} </td>
          <td> {{user.con_position}} </td>
          <td> {{user.telephone}} </td>
          <td> {{user.email_to}} </td>
          <td> {{user.mobile}} </td>
        </tr>`
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      users:
      [{ name: 1, con_position: 2, telephone: 33, email_to: 44, mobile: 555 },
      { name: 2342, con_position: 34534, telephone: 3453453, email_to: 345345, mobile: 34345345 },]
    },
    methods: {
      selectResponder(user) {
        //either...

        user.name = 4324
        console.log(user)
      }
    }
  })

</script>
```

но ничего не выходит. ошибок в консоли нет

http://codepen.io/des1roer/pen/aJLpog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) data должен возвращать объект!

```
data: function(){return {users:[]}}
```

2) Для проверки что компонент подцепляется ты можешь написать метод mounted и проверить в нем например console.log(1)

3) У тебя еще компонент вызывается который не описан `<child message="hello!"></child>`

4) Не знаю в чем именно проблема у тебя, не подцепляется шаблон, но можно сделать так

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px" id="app">       
        <users :users="users"></users>    
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
      return {
        users:
          [
            { name: 1, con_position: 2, telephone: 33, email_to: 44, mobile: 555 },
            { name: 2342, con_position: 34534, telephone: 3453453, email_to: 345345, mobile: 34345345 }
          ]
        }  
    },
    components:{
      'users': {
        'props':['users'],
        render:function (createElement) {
                    if (this.users.length) {
                      return createElement('ul', this.users.map(function (item) {
                        return createElement('li', item.name)
                      }))
                    } else {
                      return createElement('p', 'No items found.')
                    }
                  }

      }
    }

  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не работает потому, что напутали много.

1. data должен возвращать объект
2. Если используете компоненты в таблице, то нужен параметр "is": [Особенности парсинга DOM-шаблона](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-DOM-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)
3. Там же в `tr` перебор объекта и совсем другой props

Вот рабочий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>vue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px" id="app">
    <child message="hello!"></child>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>

      <tbody>
        <tr is="user" v-for="user in users" :user="user"></user>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript">
  Vue.component('user', {
    // declare the props
    props: ['user'],
    // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
    // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
    template: `        
        <tr>
          <td @click="selectResponder(user)"> {{user.name}} </td>
          <td> {{user.con_position}} </td>
          <td> {{user.telephone}} </td>
          <td> {{user.email_to}} </td>
          <td> {{user.mobile}} </td>
        </tr>`
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
        return {
              users:
              [
                { name: 1, con_position: 2, telephone: 33, email_to: 44, mobile: 555 },
                 { name: 2342, con_position: 34534, telephone: 3453453, email_to: 345345, mobile: 34345345 },
              ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      selectResponder(user) {
        //either...

        user.name = 4324
        console.log(user)
      }
    }
  })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```